# Edit inner html page befor jQuery dialog opens

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am a beginner.

```
function show()
{
        result = $.ajax({ url: "Index.aspx?cmd=fill",
            async: false,
            complete: function () {
                // unblock when remote call returns 
                $("#div_userregist").dialog("open");
            }
        }).responseText; ;
}


FormLoad() //on codebind
{
    if(request["cmd"]=="fill")
    {
      // place 1
    }
}
```

Can I do this in place 1 (see above): I edit html and then show jQuery dialog?

Comment: don't understand me wrong, but what's your mother language? - if you could state your question in Russian, Ukrainian or German i would help.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or classic ASP and is FormLoad() the page's event handler for loading the form? I'm not quite sure I understand what you want... I'm also guessing that's pseudo-code in your sample for "code behind", because that won't compile if it's ASP.NET...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?
`FormLoad() //on codebind
{
    result = $.ajax({ url: "Index.aspx?cmd=fill",
        async: false,
        complete: function (request) {
            if(request.cmd=="fill")
            {
                $('#randomelement').innerHtml = request.data;
            }
            $("#div_userregist").dialog("open");
        }
    }).responseText; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
FormLoad() //on codebind
{
if(request["cmd"]=="fill")
{
  // place 1
// edit your html here
result = $.ajax({ url: "Index.aspx?cmd=fill",
        async: false,
        complete: function () {
            // unblock when remote call returns 
            $("#div_userregist").dialog("open");
        }
    }).responseText; ;
}
}
```

Comment: this what mean. do you understant

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your comment.

Comment: What you posted there won't work. I assume FormLoad() is a server-side method and you can't access client-side scripts (like jQuery) from the server. What you propose here makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: responseText is the result which will be returned to client side. He can modify that to whatever he wants: adding jquery to edit a div, etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but like I said I'm assuming that FormLoad() is a server-side method. You can't access client-side scripts / functions from the server-side.