# edit inner html div

Tags: asp.net, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [edit inner html div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284792/edit-inner-html-div)

Having this JavaScript

```
function PopupUserRegist() { 

    result = $.ajax({ url: "Default.aspx?cmd=Setting",
        async: false ,
        complete: function () {
            // unblock when remote call returns        
        }
    }).responseText;           
 }
```

html snippet

```
<div id="div" runat ="server"></div>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["cmd"] == "Setting")
        {
              div.InnerText = "test"; //This  does not change inner text 
        }
    }



protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    div.InnerText = "test";//This   change inner text
}
```

when call PopupUserRegist(); does not change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [edit inner html div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284792/edit-inner-html-div). Just out of curiosity: how many times do you intend to ask this same question? You already have: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284241/jquery-ajax-get-date) , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284487/edit-inner-html-page-befor-jquery-dialog-opens) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283809/get-from-db-by-jquery-ajax) plus obviously the current one. If you didn't get a satisfying answer to your first question it means it was poorly asked, so update it.

Comment: Also take care about formatting your question and making sure it is understandable, otherwise people may not answer you.